# Moving things to ram

Tags: virtual-memory, memory-management, memory-limit, memory-usage, memorystick

My laptop has not been feeling well recently. When I checked​ the reasons, I found out Firefox had been performing read and write operations on the HDD at the limit of it's capabilities. After some search I found out it is possible to move Firefox cache to ram and it helped. I wondered what else could be moved to ram? Are there any downsides to this? I have 8 gb of memory at the moment, but plan to add another 8 soon.

Comment: The downsides would mostly be that rebooting your computer would be essentially the same as clearing all of your temp files. That might not be an issue for some people.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is a SSD. It’s 2017. :)

Comment: If you don't already have an SSD, they are an inexpensive and VERY worthwhile update. Besides more memory if you have less than 8GB, an SSD is the best thing you can do to breathe new life into an old or slow computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an actual answer: It depends.

Most functions of the Firefox browser should not have issues if you create a Ramdisk and move its cache location there.

There are the standard issues with Ramdisks: if your computer reboots or you lose power everything in that disk is lost with no means of recovery.

Placing the cache location on a Ramdisk does mean the cache needs to be entirely recreated each and every time you start the computer as well. which will also cause you to use more data as there will be no cached resources to refer to and sites will need to download all their resources entirely each time.

That said, getting a faster HDD in general (SSD) will likely help your computer more in general. If the slowness is just in Firefox, then you should check out which plugins are installed and remove any you no longer need. Or test the plugins to see which ones are causing the slowness and see if there are better alternatives or if you really need them.